# Can someone add a tag for [mef]

Tags: support

I am doing a lot of work in Managed Extensibility Framework and have some general questions to ask On Programmers. Can someone add an [mef] tag, or [managed-ext-framework], please?

Right now I am using [framework][net] as my tags and, while this may be *okay*, I don't feel these tags accurately target my intended audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I made one called "MEF".

Comment: muchos gracias...